# Cannot create the foreign key with the SET NULL referential action, because one or more referencing columns are not nullable

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, foreign-keys

I am creating an application where I need multiple foreign keys to a table. I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0, EF Core 7.0.11, and SQL Server 2019. I am using the code-first approach to implement this solution.

I am getting this error:

> Cannot create the foreign key "FK_GkTempGks_GkAdminUser_VerifiedBy" with the SET NULL referential action, because one or more referencing columns are not nullable.

Master entity:

```
public class GkAdminUser
{    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string? UserName { get; set; }
    public string? UserPassword { get; set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }
    public string? FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    public string Email { get; set; } = null!;
    public bool St { get; set; }   
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual GkRole? GkRole { get; set; }        

    public virtual ICollection<GkTempGks>? GkTempGkOperators { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<GkTempGks>? GkTempGkVerifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

Transaction entity:

```
public class GkTempGks
{   
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Question { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Option1 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Option2 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Option3 { get; set; } = null!;
    public string Option4 { get; set; } = null!;
    public int Answer { get; set; }
    public string? Remarks { get; set; }    
    public int Complexity { get; set; }     
    public DateTime EntryDate { get; set; }
    public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
    public DateTime? VerificationDate { get; set; }
    public string? ContentReference { get; set; }
    public int OperatorId { get; set; }      
    public int? VerifiedBy { get; set; }       
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }

    public virtual GkCategory GkCategory { get; set; } = null!;
    public virtual GkAdminUser GkOperator { get; set; } = null!;    
    public virtual GkAdminUser? GkDataVerifier { get; set; } = null!;
}
```

How do I overcome this?

Comment: From the error message I could say the mistake must be in the fluent configuration, so please include it in the post.

Answer (score 0):

EF is likely getting mixed up with the multiple references. You should be explicit about which FKs apply to which navigation properties.

```
public int OperatorId { get; set; }      
public int? VerifiedBy { get; set; }       
public int CategoryId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey(nameof(CategoryId))]
public virtual GkCategory GkCategory { get; set; } = null!;
[ForeignKey(nameof(OperatorId))]
public virtual GkAdminUser GkOperator { get; set; } = null!;    
[ForeignKey(nameof(VerifiedBy))]
public virtual GkAdminUser? GkDataVerifier { get; set; } = null!;
```

EF's convention for resolving FKs is based on the *type* of the navigation property, not the name. So by default with a navigation property like `GkAdminUser GkOperator` it will be looking for a "GkAdminUserId" FK, not "GkOperatorId", nor automatically associating an "OperatorId". You will likely also need to nominate which collection on the other end associates to each reference. This can either be done with an `[InverseProperty]` attribute or through explicitly mapping the relationship with an `.HasOne(x => x.GkOperator).WithMany(x => x.GkTempOperators)`. (`DbContext.OnConfiguring()` or with an `IEntityTypeConfiguration`)

Note that for collection navigation properties, these should not be null-able. Just initialize them with an empty collection.

```
public virtual ICollection<GkTempGks> GkTempGkOperators { get; protected set; } = new  List<GkTempGks>();
public virtual ICollection<GkTempGks> GkTempGkVerifiedBy { get; protected set; } = new  List<GkTempGks>();
```

Restrict the setters to discourage any code that might want to use the setter. Entity collection references will be set up for change tracking so they should never get re-assigned.

Comment: I have implemented your code but getting the same error.

Comment: Check exactly what VerifyBy is being associated with because the error implies that while the property is null-able, it is somehow being associated in a relationship that is not nullable.  Have you configured the inverse property get each reference to AdminUser pointing to the correct collection on the admin user side? For instance do you have a `.HasMany(x => x.GkTempGkVerifiedBy).withOne(x => x.GkDataVerifier)`?